# can't apply different templates to different nodes with same subnodes

Tags: xslt

I can't understand how from this:

```
<collection>
    <record>
     <datafield tag="700" ind1=" " ind2="1">
      <subfield code="a">David</subfield>
      <subfield code="b">M.</subfield>
      <subfield code="g">Moonstone</subfield>
      <subfield code="4">070</subfield>
    </datafield>
    <datafield tag="801" ind1=" " ind2="0">
      <subfield code="a">lang</subfield>
      <subfield code="b">EN</subfield>
      <subfield code="c">20080929</subfield>
    </datafield>
    </record>
    <record>
     <datafield tag="700" ind1=" " ind2="1">
      <subfield code="a">Samanta</subfield>
      <subfield code="b">A.</subfield>
      <subfield code="g">Aro</subfield>
      <subfield code="4">070</subfield>
    </datafield>
    <datafield tag="801" ind1=" " ind2="0">
      <subfield code="a">lang</subfield>
      <subfield code="b">JP</subfield>
      <subfield code="c">50789</subfield>
    </datafield>
    </record>
</collection>
```

get something like this:

```
person: David M. (Moonstone)
extra: lang +EN+ - 20080929

person: Samanta A. (Aro)
extra: lang +JP+ - 50789
```

this is my XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text" />
    <xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:for-each select="collection/record">
<xsl:apply-templates select="datafield[@tag='700']" />
<xsl:apply-templates select="datafield[@tag='801']" />
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="datafield[@tag='700']">
person: <xsl:apply-templates select="subfield[@code='a'] | subfield[@code='b'] | subfield[@code='g'] " />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="datafield[@tag='801']">
extra: <xsl:apply-templates select="subfield[@code='a'] | subfield[@code='b'] | subfield[@code='c'] " /></xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="subfield[@code='a'] | subfield[@code='b'] | subfield[@code='g'] "> (<xsl:value-of select="." />)</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="subfield[@code='a'] | subfield[@code='b'] | subfield[@code='c'] "><xsl:value-of select="." /> </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

which gives me this:

```
person: DavidM. (Moonstone)
extra: langEN20080929
person: SamantaA. (Aro)
extra: langJP50789
```

How to gain more control over practically identically subfields with different atributes which resides in different nodes?
I totally confused with this XPath or what is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally it is a good idea to use templates.

For templates which behave different depending on the "calling" template you can use **mode**  /e.g. `mode="extra"` ) etc.

But for your example I would suggest to do the formatting  in the parent template:
There are some possibilities to this. I use here different ones (only to show them).

Try something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"   xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="collection/record">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="datafield[@tag='700']" />
            <xsl:apply-templates select="datafield[@tag='801']" />
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="datafield[@tag='700']">
        person: <xsl:value-of select="concat( subfield[@code='a'],' ',
                                             subfield[@code='b'],' (',
                                             subfield[@code='g'], ')') " />

    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="datafield[@tag='801']" >
        extra: <xsl:apply-templates select=" subfield[@code='a']" />
        <xsl:text> +</xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates select=" subfield[@code='b']" />
        <xsl:text>+ -</xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates select=" subfield[@code='c']" />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="subfield">
        <xsl:value-of select="." />
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Which generate the following output:

```
            person: David M. (Moonstone)
            extra: lang +EN+ -20080929
            person: Samanta A. (Aro)
            extra: lang +JP+ -50789
```

Comment: I'm so newbie to this....
great thanks! I'll analyse this  clear answer and continue my learning for better understanding.